# Restore Magento Mysql db

Tags: magento-1.9, database

we have an automatic file-based backup script (from provider), we need to restore a backup done last night. Is it safe to stop mysql service, restore just the /var/lib/mysql folder and overwrite the current one, and then restart the mysql service again?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pity id doesn't work just that simply. Obvously during the (file-based) backup procedure there were some incomplete transaction, after restoring the db data we ran into several db errors. Luckily we had a system snapshot before migrating, so we could restore the db before the migration. 
So here the answer: no, the file based restore procedure of a mysqldb is not guaranteed, best way is to create a cron-based dbdump.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer that you should create other database, upload the backup on it, change the configuration and test if everything works fine.

Then you should choose which database you want to keep.